# Problems with displaying file uploaded to MSSQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm working on a form that allows the user to upload a selected file to a database.  To test and make sure the upload is successful, I'm trying to view the uploaded file.

When the file is a text file, my code works correctly and I can see the uploaded data.
However, when it's an image, I'm running into trouble.  In one case, the image partially displayed (like, the top 15% of it -- see the screenshot), and the rest is blank.[image: partial image]

In another case, I get the message "The image "my php file" cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

The database field is varbinary(max).  The file that partially displays is filesize 74403 (bytes), and the one that gives the error is 168801.  Prior to upload, I check the filesize ($_FILES['userfile']['size']) to verify it's less than 10000000 bytes.  So, I don't believe my issue is related to the file data being truncated when uploaded.

here is the related code for the upload and view:

```
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO Database.dbo.Table (name, filetype, filesize, insertdatetime, image) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES ('$filename','$filetype','$filesize',getdate(),0x".$data['hex'].");";

                // insert the image
                $result = odbc_exec($connect,$sql) or die("".odbc_errormsg());
                $id = odbc_result($result,"ID");

                $sql_view = sprintf("SELECT image,filetype FROM Database.dbo.Table WHERE id=%s;",$id);

                $result2=odbc_exec($connect,$sql_view) or die("".odbc_errormsg());
                $type = odbc_result($result2, "filetype");

                header("Content-type: $type");
                echo odbc_result($result2, "image");  

                odbc_close($connect);
```

Comment: Enable PHP error reporting. Save the picture to disk. Rename it to *.txt. Open it with a text editor. Scroll to the end. Can you see an error message of any kind?

Comment: ^ MSSQL has a way to open the field in a hex viewer too I imagine?  See this question all the time.  People just need to stop saving images in the database.  What is `$data['hex']`? result of a `unpack()?`

Comment: Alvaro:  there are no errors in the file (I also had to change the header from using $type to text/plain in order to get the file).  Ficuscr: $data['hex'] is the result of unpack() already.  This is how it's assigned:   $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']; $datastring= file_get_contents($tmpName); $data=unpack("H*hex", $datastring);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem (with both the partial image display, and the error about the image containing errors) by adding this:

```
ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "100K");
```

before my connection is made.  It overrides the default transfer limit of 4096 set in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

there will be an memory limit problem ,
thats why image contents not fully loaded.

set your php.ini

try this code n your php page you used like display.php

ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

ini_set("mssql.textlimit", "2147483647");